# HDF5 h5py segfault with MPI with Specific Numbers of MPI Threads

Tags: python, mpi, hdf5, h5py

I’ve been trying to work with HDF5 files in Python via h5py, and I get a segfault on some MPI thread counts, even in a very simple case when I call create_dataset().

My minimal failing example is shown below - the boolean can be set to cause a segfault (or not), showing that it’s dependent on whether the maxshape is set for the new array.

This is MPI-enabled, and runs with

```
mpirun -np 5 python test.py
```

It works fine for 1,2,3 and 4 MPI processes, but segfaults on with more. I presume that I have UB on the core counts where it works, too, but it just so happens it doesn't segfault in those cases.

I’ve tried this with HDF5 1.10.1 (from the openSUSE official repos) and 1.10.4 (source from the hdf5 website and compiled myself), and with h5py 2.8.0 and 2.9.0 for Python (Anaconda) 2.7. I’m using MPI 1.10.7.

I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before or has any insight. Unfortunately, I got no replies on the HDF5 forums, but I suspect there's a bug in one of the libraries.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import h5py
import numpy as np

with h5py.File('test.h5', 'w', driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD) as myfile:
    shape_tuple = (10,1)
    max_shape_tuple = (None,1)

    trigger_segfault = True 

    if trigger_segfault:
        new_array_piece = myfile.create_dataset(
                "1", shape_tuple, maxshape=max_shape_tuple
            )
    else:
        new_array_piece = myfile.create_dataset(
                    "1", shape_tuple
                )
```